# Blender draw list via script, Add Mesh: Extra Object

Tags: blender

I am trying to "visualize" a list of numbers from a .csv file. 
I could do that by writing a blender script and thats what I already did. 
But I would like to know how the Add Mesh: Extra Object - Math Function could help me (or other functions/addons/anything). 
I would like to have a 2D Line (x=+1, y=0, z= value from list) that I would rotate afterwards.
In other words can I convert a list of numbers into a function ? 
Sorry if that is a stupid question.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Where The Extra Object - Math Function addon uses minU maxU and stepU as user input values that are used to calculate the value of u before evaluating the function to generate the mesh, you want to let the user input an int value and use it as an index into an array -

```
AvailZOptions = [1.3, 2.6, 5.2, 10.4]
lineEnd = [xvalue, yvalue, AvailZOptions[OptZUserChoice]]
```

Another option would be to get the zValue from a function -

```
def CalcZValue:
    if OptZUserChoice = 1:
        return 1.3
    elif OptZUserChoice = 2:
        return 2.6 * cos(x)

lineEnd = [xvalue, yvalue, CalcZValue]
```